# Is it possible to connect android device to a printer without internet connection?

Tags: android, printing

I came across Cloud Print from google which says that it will save the document in google drive, dropbox etc.. if there is no internet connection available. I am looking for any alternative to connect android device to printer of any kind without any intermediate device.

I have a doubt too "Is connectivity concerned with printers?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printing framework in Android 4.4 only requires local connectivity to the printer. However, as this will typically be through WiFi to a network-attached printer, it may or may not cover your "no internet connection available" requirement. While the Android device does not need to reach the Internet, it would need to reach the local network enough to find the printer.

If even a local network is unavailable, now you are looking at something using Bluetooth or USB, and then you need to contact the printer manufacturer to see what options there are and whether or not they have APIs you can use from your Android app.

Similarly, if you are looking for printing support prior to Android 4.3, and Google Cloud Print is not an option, you will need to contact your printer manufacturer to see what options there are.